# Connect SharePoint Online to OWA App

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, calendar, contacts, owa

Is it possible to connect a SharePoint Online calendar to the OWA App for iPhone? If so, how? If not, what's the best way to get online/offline access to SharePoint calendars from an iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

if you still need an answer for it, here is my solution (without any other app or paid solutions) :

- Connect your Sharepoint Calendar to Outlook, and then in Outlook,
  right-click on this calendar, Share, Send this calendar via email (or
  whatever it is in English), and send it to yourself.
- It will generate an offline .ics file of the current Sharepoint
  Calendar, which will then be added to your Exchange account. It will
  be synchronized on the OWA app and in general in your iPhone or iPad.

Obviously, since it's an offline calendar you will lose the sync functionality but if you have to update it, just remove the calendar and update it with a new one, by following the same steps.

Let me know if you need any help on this.